# Is Google one-tap Sign on available for firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-identity

I tried using Google one-tap sign on on firefox. But, got an error saying:

```
{"type":"requestFailed","name":"OpenYoloError","message":"requestFailed: The API request failed to resolve: navigator.credentials error: (Missing required 'challenge' member of PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions.)"}
```

Does the One-tap feature work in other browsers or is it dependent on the navigation features of Chrome

Comment: The same works on Chrome, though. Should that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is offically supported by the new version of Google One Tap. See details at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/supported-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Firefox block third party cookies by default. So make sure you allow third party cookies for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but suddenly figured it out..

This is because there are no Google Accounts in the Browser Credentials.
In other words: just log in with a Google Account into Firefox before browsing to the site with Google One Tap...then everything will work as intended.